# How to calculate MD5 hash of multipart request body using Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, md5, multipartform-data

I am using Jersey and I need to calculate the MD5 hash of the body of a multipart post request. My current resource method signature looks like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("application/json")
public String post(
        @FormDataParam("name") String name,
        @FormDataParam("description") String description,
        @FormDataParam("iconfile") FormDataBodyPart part,
        @Context HttpServletRequest hsr) {
    // ...
}
```

I did not find a way to get the raw request body, that I need to calculate the MD5 hash. When my resource method is invoked the input stream from the `HttpServletRequest` (`hsr.getInputStream()`) is already consumed and I can not read it again.

I tried changing my method signature to the following:

```
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("application/json")
public String test(byte[] bytes) {
    // ...
}
```

This way I get the raw bytes of the request body and I can successfully calculate the MD5 hash but I don't know how to handle the multipart request from there (split the parts, get each part, etc.). Do I have to resort to handle the raw request myself? Or can I let Jersey do the dirty job and extract the `FormDataParam`s for me and let me calculate the MD5 hash somehow?

Thanks,

Comment: isn't jersey doing the dirty job already by supplying the bytes array ? why do you need to handle the parts after that ?

Comment: check the following link : http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

Comment: if you want to use byte array instead of the method in the above link, send the byte array as another parameter in addition to the name and description. don't make a single parameter which represents the whole request.

Comment: @A.J. Then how can I calculate the MD5 hash of the *whole* request? (not just from the part representing the file; my request has other parts different from the file)

Comment: a possible option is to add the following "@Context HttpServletRequest request" as a parameter in your method and then you can use the "request" to get parts or anything else.

Comment: @A.J. I have already tried that but when my resource method is invoked the input stream from the HttpServletRequest (`request.getInputStream()`) is already consumed (when mixed with `@FormDataParam`) and I can not read it again and I have no way to access the raw bytes to calculate the hash.

Comment: ok i havn't tried it myself but maybe you can try the following: get the parts from the request object and get input stream from the parts. and see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

I created a container request filter that consumes the entity input stream, calculates the MD5 checksum and sets the entity input stream again so it can be consumed by Jersey to handle the multipart request and extract the `FormDataParam`s for me.

I also injected the `HttpServletRequest` both in my filter and my resource method to communicate data between the two.

This is the filter class:

```
public class MD5CheckFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context HttpServletRequest hsr;

    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {

        byte[] bytes = request.getEntity(byte[].class); // this consumes the entity input stream
        String contentMD5 = calculateMD5(bytes);
        hsr.setAttribute("contentMD5", contentMD5);

        // set the entity input stream so it can be consumed again
        request.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

        return request;
    }

}
```

This is the relevant section of my `web.xml` within the `servlet` section:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>path.to.MD5CheckFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This way I don't need to change the original method signature:

```
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("application/json")
public String post(
        @FormDataParam("name") String name,
        @FormDataParam("description") String description,
        @FormDataParam("iconfile") FormDataBodyPart part,
        @Context HttpServletRequest hsr) {
    // ...
}
```